# How to disallow to change variable by using Developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, javascript-debugger

I try to **disallow** user to change my javascript variables by using **Developer tools** like Firebug

[image]

**My script so simple like..**

```
var a = 1;
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('div').html(a);
});
```

My site allowed to change variables by Firebug, WHY ?

After I did a demo on Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/RjQTp/), That I just to know why Fiddle **CANT** change variables by Firebug.

Can someone expain me pls...

Comment: why do you want to do this? You can basically change everything with developer tools like Firebug, what are you worried about?

Comment: Fiddle uses `iframe`. You can still change variables if you open debugger at http://fiddle.jshell.net/RjQTp/show/

Comment: That ! I think I need to dobbel check with PHP (server-side) to comfirm my vars.

Comment: Simple solution: Don't use global variables.

Comment: @FelixKling, think so, I need to scope my var(s) inside my function(s)

Comment: there is one way ... i don't know if correct but has potential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript runs on the client, and many browsers allow you to change javascripts, not just the variable values, but also inserting or deleting lines etc...

For this reason, you should always sanitize incoming data on the server side, even if it is coming from your own website..
In general, you should only consider javascript as a means to improve the UI and user's experience, but never as a means to validate, secure pages or do important business logic.

[There are some handy functions included in PHP for handling variable validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Comment: Ok, thanks, seems I have to dobbel check with server-side like PHP

Comment: @Mics yeah ! more coding :P

Comment: though its good idea to do check on client side too as if possible because it will save server some computing time if no errors at server are found. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

They can change it because it's running on their system, with their rules.

The only way to fight back is to test for changes with your actively running scripts.

I've used a system that declared each variable three times and tested my variables twice a second for changes to any set.  Then it changes and discrepancies back to the other two.

But...  They could still break my anti-cheat script with their dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(window,'a',{
  value: "test",
  enumerable: true
});
```

The code above i think, maybe makes it impossible to change, or at least very hard for anyone of my level at least. I just learned about this stuff a month ago. You know early javascript. Only way to overcome this is by deleting window object but if you do that you delete everything. If you are able to do that.

Comment: interesting, but once you set the property, you can't change it so it's very limited. And you still can't trust the data sent from the client (user can send custom ajax requests for example)

Comment: maybe cryptography can help here somehow..ugh..lol. Thinking.